# Bootstrap Datepicker update text box with month number

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have an instance of the Bootstrap datepicker set up and working well, however, what I would like to do is when a date is selected, assign the month number to a text box, lets say txt_month_number.I've had a good trawl, but examples/docs are a bit scarce.

Here is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#txt_end_date').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            weekStart: 1,
            startView: 1,
            autoclose: true,
        });
    });
});

//alert(date.getDate());       
//alert(date.getMonth        
//alert(date.getDay());          

</script>
```

I've tried various scenarios of the  .on('changeDate', function() but just can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by update a text box, but here is an example of updating a div or an input. You must assign the `.on` to the datepicker object itself:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(function() {
        $('#txt_end_date').datepicker({
            format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            weekStart: 1,
            startView: 1,
            autoclose: true,
        }).on('changeDate', function(ev){
            $("#div_txt_month_number").text($(this).val().split('/')[1]);
            $("#input_txt_month_number").val($(this).val().split('/')[1]);            
        });
    });
});
</script>

<input id="txt_end_date"/>

<div id="div_txt_month_number" class="well"></div>
<input id="input_txt_month_number" />
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/Vhtsm/2/).

Comment: Dia duit a mccanf, Daithi o Corcaigh anseo. I will give this a go and report back to you. again go raibh mile maith agat

Comment: mccanf That worked a treat,so thank you very much.If I may though,if you have the time, are you able to explain what the "ev" in the function is for?  Dave

Comment: David, ta failte romhat! You can ignore the `ev` parameter - it's only needed if you want to do something with the `changeDate` event itself.

Comment: Thanks for that, as you can see, I am yet to be vested with the ability to accept an answer, however, I will bookmark this and once able, I will.  Dave